# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]', but 'T[keyof T]' is number

Tags: typescript

What's the right way to fix this:

```
function getSumMapAndCount<T extends Partial<Record<string, number>>>({
  data,
  keys
}: {
  data: readonly T[],
  keys: readonly (keyof T)[]
}): [T, number] {
  let dataCount = 0

  const dataSumMap = data.reduce<T>((dataMap, datum) => {
    const keysToAdd = _.intersection(Object.keys(datum), keys)
    // Only count if at least one key exists
    if (keysToAdd.length === 0) {
      return dataMap
    }

    dataCount++
    keysToAdd.forEach(key => {
      const sum = dataMap[key] as number || 0
      const value = datum[key] as number || 0
      dataMap[key] = sum + value // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'.ts(2322)
    })

    return dataMap
  }, {} as T)

  return [dataSumMap, dataCount]
}
```

The issue is that T[keyof T] can be `number | undefined`, so why does it error? I know you can fix this with

```
dataMap[key] = (sum + value) as T[keyof T]
```

but I have a feeling there's something deeper at play here.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that `T extends Partial<Record<string, number>>` accepts types where the properties are *narrower* than `number`, such as [numeric literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#numeric-literal-types):

```
type Month = { days: 28 | 29 | 30 | 31; }
const months: Month[] = [{ days: 31 }, { days: 28 }, { days: 31 }, { days: 30 }];

const days = getSumMapAndCount({ data: months, keys: ["days"] })[0].days;
// const days: 28 | 29 | 30 | 31
console.log(days); // 120
```

Here, a `Month` has a `days` property that must be a whole number between 28 and 31 inclusive.  If we pass an array of `Month` objects to `getSumMapAndCount()` and ask it to sum the `days`, we get back a tuple whose first element purports to be a `Month`.  But it's not one: it has 120 days.  Oops.

---

It gets worse, I think.  If your passed-in data array has keys that you don't include in the `keys` array, `getSumMapAndCount()` returns a tuple whose first element purports to be the same type as the data.  But it will be missing keys:

```
type Point2D = { x: number, y: number };
const points: Point2D[] = [{ x: 1, y: 1 }, { x: 2, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 3 }];

const point2D = getSumMapAndCount({ data: points, keys: ["x"] })[0];
// const point2D: Point2D;
point2D.y.toFixed(); // no compiler error, runtime
```

Also oops.

---

I think we need to step back and think about exactly what the type of input and output will be and write the typing for the function correctly, then work on getting the implementation to accept it.  Here's the typing I think you have:

```
function getSumMapAndCount<K extends PropertyKey,
    T extends { [P in K]?: number }>({ data, keys }: {
        data: readonly T[],
        keys: readonly K[]
    }): [{ [P in K]?: number }, number] {
```

For each key in the union `K` corresponding to the elements of the `keys` array, we only constrain `T` to either not have that key or have a `number` property at that key.  We don't care about any other keys.  And importantly, the output type is only claiming to be a map from (some subset of) the keys in `K` to `number`.  So, if `T` is `Month`, and `K` is `"days"`, the first element of the output will be `{days?: number}` and not `Month`.  That's good.  Let's see what has to happen in the implementation:

```
    let dataCount = 0

    const dataSumMap = data.reduce((dataMap, datum) => {
        const keysToAdd = keys.filter(k => k in datum); // changed this
        // Only count if at least one key exists
        if (keysToAdd.length === 0) {
            return dataMap
        }

        dataCount++
        keysToAdd.forEach(key => {
            const sum = dataMap[key] as number || 0
            const value = datum[key] as number || 0
            dataMap[key] = sum + value;
        })

        return dataMap
    }, {} as { [P in K]?: number })

    return [dataSumMap, dataCount]
}
```

The only real difference there is that I assert the initial map to be a `Partial<Record<K, number>>` (or the equivalent `{[P in K]?: number}`) instead of `T`.  Then everything else just works.  (Note that I don't have lodash so I changed your use of `intersection` to an array filter; do what you want there).  Let's see if it works:

```
const days = getSumMapAndCount({ data: months, keys: ["days"] })[0].days;
// const days: number | undefined
console.log(days); // 120 

const justX = getSumMapAndCount({ data: points, keys: ["x"] })[0];
// const justX: {x?: number | undefined} 
justX.y.toFixed(); // compiler error!
//    ~ <-- there's no y on {x?: number | undefined}
```

That looks better now.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAFATgewEYBsJiQG8AoJMpAFwE8ZkBZDYCgCyQF4ikATEKqALiQAmABxIAPsICcEpAGYADLLkBGANxIAvqXLxGUCkjCMWApAybMA2gF12SK4W68zqrQBpOPPoNEevLoJump5O3q5KmjZqxDpkesAGznz2AOYQFADKAK5gdCAwAILAXADCGNlMABRhIBQggsaWUJ4A1hA+DgBE4V12mgCUVgo2AHThMeRIAPTTSAlJ4b5ikkIykorKKnHz+hh4ozgYqVXhAxqzSCpCSoB8G4Aou7FT1LSoGACWTEIAIvZOAB6CYC5LAQNCeKhAkFgrSTXT6QwwD5MMwoZEUH62eyOJCAq4QwQqfwA3wE4TE3FBMlyLTRJ7wxKI9E-NIZHJ5ArFMoVaq1eqCJGfCgtJDtTpWLr-PpaIYjOFkS4LJlCn6CNEq77ypCCr7fUZUUYUDAAMXe-wgXCq5xmc2AGF2YBg7zwaCQYMw4KQaEqFHekCQgF4NwClO-SyAAzSrwX2MJDpLK5fJFErlH0AHgAKm7-hQICUoKgQGhfSAcKmAEoQPRoLipgxoT6pTzAsCgtAAPg7NR2Ux49Xc3fIYqgO00ghIUx7dQaXogIC4jBwVCQ6ds-Yng46ZjQs-nwEXSCqYowYeXQxsI4Ggis6ab0LQdnH66QeEMvZAKaY9gUoYnSuc9XZRN7DfUZty4bJEAzNsqlOKdE08XtcgGdg2yIAd1z-Id0wwQouC4ewh1GMNnRzNBDxQ0UkE+f8kK1J8bSQAB5Pclz0H0qJPOpn1nJJGGQMUs3eAxh3oqZ3hPQ9N2w3CuEOXNUhYdg2A4BRkMfUSJ23ChsjQYB-xARN0InbQjMneoPwoABqSzTI3PhpLwoiMDQABRBBmEkpc2FQ9SNIZJIoFyYC4IKKwxTsEB82bVsJEkb8-N-BEkAANxLbJkA4RCwDCjoIqiu9YqQeKEvIN9Exyqg7A4QKCEslK0uQS50xoZAAHJorBVqqKijBDEiqB3lSUBcGQI1KBapBWpXI8T3TGxWsNKAqiEOQhCEAZbLIQYf3orSdL0sqCiMkIiE0JBItPHbyD23SHDfQCCgQqcLPPKZtBM0BIFgBBkFNc18JIH8I2AKN3hjOMHqTbk0wAaSzHM81QTBaCLKgYY6Ncn0zCBs1zLh8ycKwUCovSYZsAB+KEWxhTRoL5EA2k3LQx02-TBG3OcFyXFcbExjSh3ZncuaQGHbGOy8HEJ4nqLJymkA610ToVh8jJffSLK-K74iS+6EwKYL6lAi0IIgGDDpgJ7tLAZDvLQhLMKknC8IIzciJIsFyNt1oSZo626KfS5mP3NjP3E87DDwSLDD40UOkE4TWbDzyoAc2S8GABTWGUlS1NZqYboOkKYFZkyErfCzrNZrCndksNnLc+APIE23fPtpKaoNgzQvC878up11xDivP-MMVKcHSg3cgqvL5YKweiuHshzen+wO7qsf0v99dttZgv9MM+iTsIM6Lqln3ZapmKd92jJ9ruqdIct98eQoV7yBMnYXnoEws4CTo-FWOseQSgNjqC0DsP8TRTCCAsCwLEHAcRLHkESI+yQzB+FQUg4IoQ0FBEiHSCBOsXCsnjByKGFkahsyMD-EUAtui9H6LKMYEwdiKiIZ0BWshKhcAgMRYAFpCGJH2BAQ4xxYJ8GtJca4SgAyAFkdn8X83gaj+LiOWCsyScM0FqP8OphRqmZN8eBktKT4iQJCK4FI8RCDJEISxVIzFBFpDEQRSQABW2QDAAA0SGQy5BQ+mAp0S0M3FeSU0pBjDDpFMNhjIkDuK8WOf4ai55IG4bwz4FozpyJ2PEignj9SGhNGaC0VoLhzD0I6Z0MJ3TOQAISsLmOQAAfkgVMABaNplBmBgggK1HqZikAxkIEky+MJJBpL4Zkp4sRNBAA)