# Typescript using get<T>(key: keyof T): T[key] --- return type to be specifically the type of the property on T, not T[keyof T]

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I've followed these couple of issues that are similar on stackoverflow [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62206138/type-number-is-not-assignable-to-type-tkeyof-t-but-tkeyof-t-is-number) and [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62206138/type-number-is-not-assignable-to-type-tkeyof-t-but-tkeyof-t-is-number) among of another handful of issues, but none of them really address the specific use-case and issue I'm having so I decided to ask a new question.

My use case:

- I have a "getConfig" function.
- I have several config classes, such as "AppConfig" and "UsersConfig"
- All config classes have unique keys with explicit type definitions.
- I want consumers of getConfig to provide `getConfig<T extends AppConfig | UsersConfig>(key: keyof T)`
- I don't want to also pass the Config class as an input parameter.

My issue:

- I can't construct a type that targets the actual type within the config class, for example:

```
class AppConfig {
app_name: string = "Application Name"
}
class UsersConfig{
max_users: number = 5
}

getConfig<AppConfig>("app_name"): typeof AppConfig["app_name"] // I want this to be string
getConfig<UsersConfig>("max_users"): typeof UsersConfig["max_users"] // I want this to be number
getConfig("app_name") // I'd like this to throw, doesn't
getconfig<AppConfig>("max_users") // throws which is good
```

The response types of the two calls above are of course wrong and don't pass the compiler.
I've been studying Conditional and Overloads in typescript for some time & asked on groups but I still didn't manage to design a working solution.

Side Issue:

- Currently if a consumer calls getConfig("something") and does not provide a generic, the compiler doesn't say anything and functionality silently fails throughout the application, is there a way to prevent this?

The closest I came to this was `: T[keyof T]` which creates a Union Type based on the types of all keys of T, which isn't working for my purpose.

Thank you.

Comment: The requirement here is to provide config type as a generic parameter explicitly and infer the key type. The closest you can get know is "curried" version https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCAO8DCB7AdgMwJYHNoG8BYAKGmjEQH00wBbAUwC5oIAXAJyzTwF5oAiBPBBZgYVlnTQAcnXr8SAXxKhIMAKoR67CKky4CJMrTAAPSgFctO5mgu0ARtuh8ArEpIkAJvVXt60BgWaMASUjj0rHrYOAA8ACrQ9Kas9GheMELRBgA+0JrauugxAHwAFACUzLEA0kkpaRnQANb0AJ4oGNDx5a1tzDUVLiXdANo1ALqexMDobOSIsgwu0BFRxbixWRs45RVl-BTw1HL8QwD05ywcXDgqc6zQJqYF7Ctr2XGvRfq7lQfPSzWCBnaCXaB2RzaEgfHb-Q5UGgMUHg1gAC3YKAA7kA Partial inference is not supported yet.

Comment: by what I'm seeing in the playground this accomplishes everything i'm looking for at the more than acceptable expense of calling the config function `getConfig()("something")`. I'll give it a go at implementing tomorrow and get back to you. 

Meanwhile, if you post this as a response withe the code in the playground as text, I'm more than happy to mark it as the answer :) 

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to infer property type based on provided key we need to introduce generic type parameter for key. Currently partial [type inference is not supported](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242), so in order to be able to specify the config type explicitly but infer the key type - currying can be used:

```
class AppConfig {
  app_name: string = "Application Name"
}
class UsersConfig {
  max_users: number = 5
}

declare function getConfig<T extends AppConfig | UsersConfig>(): <K extends keyof T>(key: K) => T[K]

const appName = getConfig<AppConfig>()("app_name") // string
const maxUser = getConfig<UsersConfig>()("max_users") // number
getConfig()("app_name") // throws
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCAO8DCB7AdgMwJYHNoG8BYAKGmjEQH00wBbAUwC5oIAXAJyzTwF5oAiBPBBZgYVlnTQAcnXr8SAXxKhIMAKoR67CKky4CJMrTAAPSgFctO5mgu0ARtuh8ArEpIkAJvVXt60BgWaMASUjj0rHrYOAA8ACrQ9Kas9GheMELRBgA%200JrauugxAHwAFACUzLEA0kkpaRnQANb0AJ4oGNDx5a1tzDUVLiXdANo1ALqexMDobOSIsgwu0BFRxbixWRs45RVl-BTw1HL8QwD05ywcXDgqc6zQJqYF7Ctr2XGvRfq7lQfPSzWCBnaCXaB2RzaEgfHb-Q5UGgMUHg1gAC3YKAA7hAgA)